# Issue with Hadoop HA configuration

Tags: hadoop, high-availability

I have followed the edureka blog for HA configuration.

Link : http://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-set-up-hadoop-cluster-with-hdfs-high-availability/

Everything seems to be coming fine, except the failover daemons

i.e. i have **3 nodes(NN1, NN2 and DN1)** and have daemons Namenode, JournalNode, QuorumPeerMain

But when executing command  `hdfs zkfc formatZK`, it is throwing error.

When checked the logs, it says

> Operation category JOURNAL is not supported in state standby

I also have executed 2 more commands

```
hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn1 -- status shown is standby

hdfs haadmin -getServiceState nn2 -- status shown is standby
```

**Issue** : None of the namenode is in active mode.

Please suggest what is going wrong.

**Note**:  I have the property of automatic-failover in hdfs-site.xml set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the commands in the next order:

First start zookeeper: `zkServer.sh start`

Then the next commands:

1. (only on namenode 1): `hdfs zkfc -formatZK`
2. (on all namenodes): `hadoop-daemon.sh start journalnode`
3. (only on namenode 1): `hadoop namenode -format`
4. (only on namenode 1): `hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`
5. (only on namenode 2): `hadoop namenode -bootstrapStandby`
6. (only on namenode 2): `hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`
7. (on all namenodes): `hadoop-daemon.sh start zkfc`